# Parse error in sql query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql =" CREATE TABLE `".$tbl."`
(
id int,
sc_no varchar(255),
name varchar(255),";
foreach($sub in $subs){ $sql .= " $sub varchar(255)," } 
$sql .="status varchar(255))";
```

I am getting a parse error on line 6.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the parse error isn't in the SQL query per se.

The PHP code is wrong:

```
foreach($sub in $subs)
```

should be

```
foreach($subs as $sub)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should code as bellow:

foreach($subs **as $sub**){ $sql .= " $sub varchar(255),"**;** }